# How do i get an accessToken after authenticating with Neura sdk for Android

Tags: android, neura

When using ([neura sdk](https://dev.theneura.com/docs/guide/android/sdk)) to detect where the user was, and what he/she's been doing 30 minutes ago.

We've followed their guide for interacting with neara, and managed to authenticate with Neura successfully.

For our server side, we need to use neura's api request for [receiving the user's situation](https://dev.theneura.com/docs/api/insights#progressiveSituation).
The problem is that we don't have the accessToken as described in the link.

Were do i get this accessToken from ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take it from : SDKUtils

mNeuraApiClient is an instance of `com.neura.standalonesdk.service`

```
import com.neura.standalonesdk.util;

SDKUtils.isConnected(getApplicationContext(), mNeuraApiClient);
```